# How can I redraw or resize the rectangle in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to redraw and resize the rectangle which is drawn to detect objects. And initially i am able to fetch the data through JSON file and able to draw rectangle based on JSON's x,y,width & height data.

Now I wanted to redraw or resize it. How can i do that?

Approach : Once user press EDIT button all the rectangle bounding box will converts in to dotted box and later as per user requirement, user can access that any particular rectangle & it can be resize or re drawable.Once it is done user has to press the save button and whatever new changes we made it automatically reflect to same json file with new Json data.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a6y4dq0/3/) for drawing an object.

Json file format:

```
{
    "Frame_count":1,
    output:[
        {
        "Objects_classname":"car1",
            "x_val":82.9883,
            "y_val":197.56245,
            "width":316.03088,
            "height":197.45451
        },

        {
        "Objects_classname":"car2",
            "x_val":522.4823,
            "y_val":170.47263,
            "width":64.66687,
            "height":61.78085
        },

        ],
        "Total_objects_detected":2,
},
{
    "Frame_count":2,
    output:[
        {
        "Objects_classname":"car1",
            "x_val":78.9991,
            "y_val":189.48058,
            "width":327.41028,
            "height":198.80226
        },

        {
        "Objects_classname":"car2",
            "x_val":506.45404,
            "y_val":170.87161,
            "width":67.57983,
            "height":52.28577
        },

        ],
        "Total_objects_detected":2,
}
```

[In image you see the rectangle boxes around pedestrian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhmT.png)

Comment: Let me know if I am missing anything in above question

Comment: you assingment of new values is probably wrong as the rectangle is drawn from objetos in actualizar not from objetoActual

Comment: ya you are right but how can i update it?

Comment: This is my code which gets the data from JSON and draws a Rectangle : https://jsfiddle.net/kypq28uz/1/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid gray"></div>
<p>Click the button to send JSON Size</p>
<button type="button" onclick="newSize()">new size</button>
<script>
  var _main = document.getElementById("main");
  var _size = {
        "width": "200px",
        "height": "200px",
        "border" : "2px solid gray"
      };
  function newSize() {
    _main.style.width = _size.width
    _main.style.height = _size.height
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here main problem is that First I m drawing a rectangle using JSON data and later I wanted to edit it. So How can I select particular rectangle first, if I am able to select I can resize it.

Comment: check this link :(https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/74/)  Here I am giving rectangle height and width in CSS but in my case It is coming from JSON file so how can I apply same mechanism to my code?

Comment: How can I put JSON's x,y,w,h instead of #main in above jsfiddle?

Comment: not sure how your fiddler works with pure js looks like some library is used. However changed the code example

Comment: In example code I am not able to resize or drag using mouse events

Comment: no that's done through your javscript library which makes the code aware of $